# How can I stop my MFC application from calling OnFileNew() when it starts?

Tags: c++, mfc

I used Visual Studio's Application Wizard to create a skeleton MFC program with a multi-document interface.  When I start this program, it automatically creates a child frame, which I don't want it to do - I need the main frame's client area to be empty until the user chooses to open a file.

The debugger tells me that a CChildFrame object is created when the application class's InitInstance() function calls ProcessShellCommand(), but what is a good entry point for me to override this behaviour?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This worked for me -- change

```
if (!ProcessShellCommand(cmdInfo))
```

to

```
if (cmdInfo.m_nShellCommand != CCommandLineInfo::FileNew && !ProcessShellCommand(cmdInfo))
```

in your app's InitInstance() function.

Comment: It works!  But will skipping ProcessShellCommand() altogether have unwanted consequences?  What does that function do?  (I've failed to find its definition in my project.)

Comment: I've looked it up in the Visual Studio docs, and it looks like all the function does is to process the parameter, so this is great.  Thanks again.

Comment: Because you're only skipping the "FileNew" command, which you don't want to do on startup anyway, I don't think it will be a problem. You're still processing the other commands, so I think it will still work if for instance you passed a filename to open on the command line. (But I haven't tried it.)

Answer (score 6):

This works, it maintains printing/opening from the shell etc.

```
// Parse command line for standard shell commands, DDE, file open
CCommandLineInfo cmdInfo;
ParseCommandLine(cmdInfo);

if ( cmdInfo.m_nShellCommand == CCommandLineInfo::FileNew )
{
    cmdInfo.m_nShellCommand = CCommandLineInfo::FileNothing ;
}

// Dispatch commands specified on the command line
if (!ProcessShellCommand(cmdInfo))
    return FALSE;
```

Comment: I think this is equivalent to jeffm's answer.  It's longer but clearer, and it's closer to what I ended up doing.

Answer (score 1):

Skipping the ProcessShellCommand() call (in case of FileNew) in InitInstance() is indeed the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

Do one thing..

in your XXXApp.cpp file

in this Method:-

comment the following line..
/*

```
    CCommandLineInfo cmdInfo;
ParseCommandLine(cmdInfo);

// Dispatch commands specified on the command line.  Will return FALSE if
// app was launched with /RegServer, /Register, /Unregserver or /Unregister.
if (!ProcessShellCommand(cmdInfo))
    return;
```

*/

like this....